# using setTimeout or setInterval with a string type function callee name

Tags: flash, actionscript-2, settimeout, setinterval

I am trying to randomly call one of the below mentioned function every one second. here is the code that I have.

```
counter=Math.floor(1+Math.random()*3); // genertate random number from 1 to 3

setTimeout("startenemy"+counter, 1000); // call one function with a delay of one second

function startenemy1()
{
    trace("1");
    enemy1.gotoAndPlay(2);
}
function startenemy2()
{
    trace("2");
    enemy2.gotoAndPlay(2);
}

function startenemy3()
{
    trace("3");
    enemy3.gotoAndPlay(2);
}
```

The setTimeout function is not working for me in this scenario.
But if I use a very primitive way of using setTimeout, it works just fine.

```
setTimeout(startenemy1, 1000); // call one function with a delay of one second

function startenemy1()
{
trace("1");
enemy1.gotoAndPlay(2);
}
```

this implementation works just fine. So I know that I am using the setTimeout function with incorrect arguments.

Please let me know if there is another way to make this happen.

Comment: Note that you need to call clearTimeout each time you call setTimeout and before disposing of the Class using setTimeout, because calling setTimeout gives the main Flash Player a hard reference to the function (and hence the entire Class), which can cause a memory leak!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the bracket syntax to obtain a reference to the function:

```
var counter=Math.floor(1+Math.random()*3);  
var method:Function = this["startenemy"+counter];
setTimeout( method, 1000);
```

But it would be more efficient to have a single method that starts an anonymous MovieClip, and reference the enemy movie clips dynamically:

```
function startEnemy( mc:MovieClip ) : void {
    mc.gotoAndPlay(2);
}

var counter=Math.floor(1+Math.random()*3);  
var mc:MovieClip = this["enemy"+counter];
setTimeout( startEnemy, 1000, mc); // mc will become the first parameter
                                   // passed to startEnemy()
```

Comment: That was dot on. Since I am new to flash/AS I was unaware of type:function. thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 1):

setTimout takes a parameter of type Function. Something like this will work :

```
function startenemy1():void
{
    trace("1");
    enemy1.gotoAndPlay(2);
}
function startenemy2():void
{
    trace("2");
    enemy2.gotoAndPlay(2);
}

function startenemy3():void
{
    trace("3");
    enemy3.gotoAndPlay(2);
}

function startARandomEnemy():void
{
  var functions:Array = [startenemy1,startenemy2,startenemy3];
  setTimeout(functions[int(Math.random()*functions.length)], 1000); // call one function with a delay of one second
}
```

A better design would be to store the enemy objects in an array instead of making functions named startenemy*().

Comment: thanks for the answer. This method surely works. I will keep it in mind.